# Which spells can do damage twice or more through movement?

Tags: dota-2

Afaik there are spells like QoPs ultimate who did twice the damage in dota 1 if the target was forcestaffed from QoP so the end of the ultimate would hit again.

Is this still possible in DotA2 and if so which spells do have this ability?

Comment: Have not noticed it happening in ~1750 games, but that doesn't mean it's not possible.

Comment: I have witnessed it a few times with clock's cogs and once with QoP ulti (magina got hit a second time after a blink. However that was like 1,5-2 years ago and those might have happenned 4 or 5 times in my 2,5k+ game of DotA 2. The bugs might have been fixed and some other spell could be buggy to. The only way would be to test those kind of aoe spells

Comment: i could not reproduce with kotl, qop and dp. so i would say it is fixed and if some spell still has this behavior it is inconsistent and should be considered a bug.

Comment: @Wandang I want to test this with Tidehunter.

Comment: @Decency if you are testing consider testing dk's breath, thd breath and linas wave too please. those are short and quick so it will be hard to test but for completeness it would be good to test them.

Comment: @Wandang Tested with all 3. Definitely not possible with Ravage, wasn't able to repro with other spells either. My guess is that internally they use a debuff ID of some sort for each spell that prevents reapplication of damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no ultimate which does damage twice due to location changes of the target. I googled as well for qop double ultimate...didn't find anything working for dota 2.

You can of course take bloodseekers ultimate which does damage when the target travels, so force staffing the target will cause damage. But that's not what we are looking for.

Comment: http://www.playdota.com/forums/showthread.php?t=162764 Kotl is another example in dota1 that gets confirmed there

Comment: i just tested with kotl, dp and qop and could not reproduce it. please delete the part from dota1 (because you were wrong there) so i can remove the downvote and accept the answer

Comment: done. hmmm okay makes sense kotl...I remember when force staff was introduced into dota and they were experimenting a lot but that was new to me as well. thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is 1 so far ive seen which is bara charge seen in one of the fails of the week idk if its lucky or what but the np who was cliff jungling got bashed twice in a row when bara is charging Through him

Comment: could you link that video? to me this seems to be a bug and not intentional.